# NullPointException on algorithm but don't get NPE on same algorithm in another spot in same class

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

In my app, the user has 3 different types of quizzes they can choose.  When they choose one of quiz types called "levels", I get a `NullPointerException`.  The order of the algorithm for "levels" is the same as when the game type is "original".  You can see this in the code below.  It is hard to explain why the algorithms are the same so I will spare you those details but just accept the algorithms are the same for now.  :)

Why am I getting this NPE exception with the quiz/game type is "levels" but not when the quiz/game type is "original" even though the code/algorithm for them are the same?

```
public class QuestionView extends Activity  {

    int correctAnswers = 0;
    int wrongAnswers = 0;
    int answer = 0;
    int i = 0;

    long score = 0;

    long startTime = 20000;
    long interval = 1000;
    long points;

    boolean timerHasStarted = false;

    String category;

    Button answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4;
    TextView question, pointCounter, questionNumber, timeCounter, timeremaining;

    ArrayList<Question> queries;
    public static ArrayList<Long> pointsPerQuestion = new ArrayList<Long>(10);
    Timer cdTimer;

    ProgressBar bar;

    Context c;

    Singleton singleton = Singleton.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.questionview);

        c = this;

        answer1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        answer2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        answer3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        answer4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer4);

        question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
        questionNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questionnumber);
        timeremaining = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeremaining);

        category = getIntent().getStringExtra("category");
        queries = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("queries");

        pointsPerQuestion.clear();

        if(singleton.getGameType() == "levels") {

            if(singleton.getLevel() <= 10) {

                cdTimer = new Timer(startTime, interval);
                bar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
                bar.setIndeterminate(false);
                bar.setMax(20000);

                loadLevelsQuizTen();
            }

            //...

        } else if (singleton.getGameType() == "original") {

            cdTimer = new Timer(startTime, interval);
            bar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
            bar.setIndeterminate(false);
            bar.setMax(20000);

            loadOriginalQuiz();

        } else if (singleton.getGameType() == "freeplay") {

            loadFreeplayQuiz();

        }
    }

    public void loadFreeplayQuiz() {

        //...

    }

    public void loadLevelsQuizTen() {

        if(i == 10) {

            cdTimer.cancel();
            endQuiz();

        } else {

            if(!timerHasStarted) {
                cdTimer.start();
                timerHasStarted = true;
            } else {
                cdTimer.start();
                timerHasStarted = false;
            }

            //answer = queries.get(i).getCorrectAnswer();  //NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION HERE
            answer = 2;    

            question.setText(queries.get(i).getQuery());  // I COMMENTED OUT ABOVE LINE OF CODE AND NOW NPE IS NOW HERE

            answer1.setText(queries.get(i).getA1());
            answer2.setText(queries.get(i).getA2());
            answer3.setText(queries.get(i).getA3());
            answer4.setText(queries.get(i).getA4());

            answer1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                //...
                }
            });

            answer2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                //...
            });

            answer3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                //...
            });

            answer4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                //...
            });
        } 
    }

    public void loadOriginalQuiz() {

        if(i == 10) {

            cdTimer.cancel();
            endQuiz();

        } else {

            if(!timerHasStarted) {
                cdTimer.start();
                timerHasStarted = true;
            } else {
                cdTimer.start();
                timerHasStarted = false;
            }

            answer = queries.get(i).getCorrectAnswer();

            question.setText(queries.get(i).getQuery());

            answer1.setText(queries.get(i).getA1());
            answer2.setText(queries.get(i).getA2());
            answer3.setText(queries.get(i).getA3());
            answer4.setText(queries.get(i).getA4());

            answer1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                //...
            });

            answer2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                //...
            });

            answer3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                //...
            });

            answer4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                //...
            });
        } 
    }

    public ArrayList<Question> getQueries() {
        return queries;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Long> getPointsPerQuestion() {
        //...
    }

    public void correct() {
        pointsPerQuestion.add(points); 
        score = score + points;
        i++;
        if(singleton.getGameType() == "original") {
            loadOriginalQuiz();
        } else if(singleton.getGameType() == "levels") {
            loadLevelsQuizTen();
        }
    }

    public void incorrect() {
        long zero = 0;
        pointsPerQuestion.add(zero);
        i++;
        loadOriginalQuiz();
    }

    public class Timer extends CountDownTimer {

        public Timer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            points = 0;
            if(i >= 9) {
                cdTimer.cancel();
                pointsPerQuestion.add(points);
                endQuiz();
            } else {
                wrongAnswers++;
                incorrect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            bar.setProgress((int) millisUntilFinished);
            points = (millisUntilFinished / 200) + 1;
            timeremaining.setText("Score remaining: " + points);
            if(i < 10) {
                questionNumber.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.question) + " " + (i + 1) + " " + c.getResources().getString(R.string.of10));
            }
        }
    }

    public void endQuiz() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionView.this, Results.class);
        intent.putExtra("correctAnswers", correctAnswers);
        intent.putExtra("wrongAnswers", wrongAnswers);
        intent.putExtra("score", score);
        intent.putExtra("pointsPerQuestion", pointsPerQuestion);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("queries", queries);
        intent.putExtra("category", category);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

LogCat

```
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite/matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.QuestionView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.QuestionView.loadLevelsQuizTen(QuestionView.java:195)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.QuestionView.onCreate(QuestionView.java:80)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Comment: First. Don't compare string using `==`. Use `equals()` instead

Comment: I will fix that.  Thank  you.

Answer (score 3):

Why "accept"?  That might be the fatal flaw in your argument.

Here's the problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 20:44:45.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.QuestionView.loadLevelsQuizTen(QuestionView.java:195)
```

Go to line 195 in the QuestionView.java file, look at the object references on that line, and see which one you failed to initialize.

The sooner you stop telling yourself that everything is fine and start looking at what's really happening, the sooner you'll fix the problem and move on.

You should not be duplicating any code.  You should encapsulate it in a single method call and calling it in both places.  This is a recipe for error.

You have lots of other issues.  You use a private data member i to do different things in different methods.  It's not synchronized in any way that I can see.  I see no reason why that value couldn't be a method parameter and passed in.  That would be more more thread safe.

When you're doing things like that, comparing Strings with ==, and duplicating code it puts everything you've done in doubt for me.  No wonder you're having trouble.  Voting to close.

Comment: I commented in line 195 that the NPE was there in my code.  You can see where I commented out a line above 195 that I have troubleshot some and ruled out that the variable `queries` and the `.get(i)` part of the code is not the issue.  The reason the algorithms are the same right now is because I was troubleshooting my code.  I had `if(singleton.getLevel() <= 10) { loadLevelsQuizTen }` as this:  `if(singleton.getLevel() <= 10) { loadOriginalQuiz }`.  So I have replicated the code into 2 separate methods with the same algorithm in my attempt to troubleshoot.  Sorry if confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Set a breakpoint where you are getting the NPE and check the values of your variables. I would guess either `queries` is null (not setting or getting from intent bundle correctly), or `queries.get(i)` is null.

Comment: When I comment out `answer = queries.get(i).getCorrectAnswer();` and replace it with `answer = 2;` I still get the NPE error.  So that rules out that the `queries` variable or the `.get(i)` is the issue.

Comment: it is impossible for a null pointer exception to get thrown on the line `answer = 2;`, so something is wrong with the way you are debugging/compiling.

Comment: Oh man, you're right.  I thought I had carefully looked at that and made sure, but apparently not!  The NPE is now on the line below it:  `question.setText(queries.get(i).getQuery());`.

Comment: so your options for null variables are `question`, `queries`, or `queries.get(i)`

Comment: I will try to step through this and find whats the problem but I just cannot figure out why if the code goes to the `loadOriginalQuiz()` method, no NPE error happens even though the same code is in that method.

Answer (score 0):

you get the error because you are calling 2 different methods. In levels you call `loadLevelsQuizTen();`, in original you call `loadOriginalQuiz();`

Despite the fact you say they are the same, they aren't. I'd use a debugger to step through the method and figure out what is null and why.